# How to interpret the results of a logistic regression in python

Tags: logistic, python, interpretation, regression-coefficients, statsmodels

When I run a logistic regression using sm.Logit (from the statsmodel library), part of the result looks like this:

[image]

The variable y is academic success (average greater than 10). The problem is that I am lost in front of this table (there is only the beginning), I do not know how to interpret the results. In the coef column, can I interpret only the sign or the value too? For "absences" I can say what with -0.0459? Also what does column "z" mean and what can I say on it? The confidence interval I understood but the beginning is quite blurry for me, can you help me please?

Comment: If this is logistic regression then the variable is presumably the log-odds of academic success, so if the probability of success is $p_i$ then this is estimating a regression for $\log\left(\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\right)$ in the form $\beta_0+\beta_1\text{ studymore} +  \beta_2\text{ absences} + \beta_3\text{ failures} +\cdots$, and you can use this to transform the estimated log-odds back to probabilities $\hat p_i$.  The estimated `coefs` are the $\beta$s with their `std err` (standard errors), and the confidence intervals are close to these coefficients $\pm \, 2$  standard errors.

Answer (score 2):

The logistic regression model is

$$
E[y|X_1,X_2,\dots,X_k] = \sigma(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \dots + \beta_k X_k)
$$

The `coef` column displays the $\beta_0,\beta_1,\dots$ parameters, where $\beta_0$ is described as `const`. On the interpretation of the parameters you can read in the following threads:

- [interpretation of model coefficient in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482290/interpretation-of-model-coefficient-in-logistic-regression)
- [Regression coefficient interpretation in binary logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198428/regression-coefficient-interpretation-in-binary-logistic-regression)
- [Binary logistic regression: interpretation of regression coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199071/binary-logistic-regression-interpretation-of-regression-coefficients)

The `z` column shows the $Z$ values discussed in:

- [Logistic Regression Z-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363322/logistic-regression-z-value)
- [Z test vs Wald Test in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262765/z-test-vs-wald-test-in-logistic-regression)
- [Why use a z test rather than a t test with proportional data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90893/why-use-a-z-test-rather-than-a-t-test-with-proportional-data)

Those are just examples of multiple threads we have, so check other questions tagged as [logistic-regression](/questions/tagged/logistic-regression) for more details.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand, with your second link if I understand correctly, the effect of "absences" corresponds to (1-0.9545) = 0.0455 so a 4.55% decrease in the chance of having the average ? it seems strange to me.

I need to do this regression for a little homework, if I just interpret the significance of the coefficients with their signs, can this be enough as an analysis? (for significance I look at P>|z|?)